# How to handle specific route address in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a specific route like:

```
http://localhost:3000/Transaction?Authority=A00000000000000000000000000111&Status=NOK
```

But I don't know how to handle this url, here I used:

```
        <Route path="/Transaction/:Authority/:Status" element={<Cart />} />
```

When I entered this URL, it won't redirect me to the Cart component.  Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: you pass data in query params and routes are diff.
`http://localhost:3000/Transaction/Authority=A00000000000000000000000000111/Status=NOK
`

Answer (score 1):

For a URL path such as: `"/Transaction?Authority=A00000000000000000000000000111&Status=NOK"`

There is only a single path segment and two queryString params. An example `Route` may look as follows:

```
<Route path="/Transaction" element={<Cart />} />
```

The queryString params can be accessed within the `Cart` component via the [`useSearchParams` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams)

```
const { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

const authority = searchParams.get("Authority"); // "A00000000000000000000000000111"
const status = searchParams.get("Status");       // "NOK"
```

If you instead are really wanting to use `path="/Transaction/:Authority/:Status"` then you should compose your link a little differently

```
`"/Transaction/A00000000000000000000000000111/NOK"`

const { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { Authority, Status } = useParams();
```

then use the [`useParams` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) to access the route match params